# Monitor kids' messages/devices

Tags: monitoring, parental-control

I'd like to be able to monitor my kids devices and what they're searching. Without being the bad guy and ask him for their devices to install software they think I'm evil because I want to monitor what they're doing but they're teenagers

Comment: This has nothing to do with Tor. This would be general computing depending on the operating system that is on your kids' computers. In fact what you're asking is the opposite of Tor since Tor is about being anonymous. 

The superuser group might be a better place for this question. https://superuser.com. Remember to say which operating system that you are using on your computers.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because because it has nothing to do with Tor.

Comment: What kind of devices (Android, iOS, Windows, Linux, Mac, other)? Do you want to monitor only in your home (at the router), or also when they are away from home?

Answer (score 1):

They have a right for privacy, stop breaking their international human rights and start being a teacher and a leading example to them!

Comment: So, which software are you recommending? ;-)